# How do I get the same DIV name or id when it change into an input field?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make an editable list like MySQL, but I can't get the same [DIV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Other_block_elements) id when it's changed to an input field. How can I do that?

This is my code...

```js
//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function() {
  $.fn.editable = function() {
    var textBlocks = $(this);

    for (var i = 0; i < textBlocks.length; i += 1) {
      var textBox = $('<input class="my-text-box" onchange="myFunction(this.value)" />');
      var textBlock = textBlocks.eq(i);
      textBox.hide().insertAfter(textBlock).val(textBlock.html());
    }

    textBlocks.dblclick(function() {
      toggleVisiblity($(this), true);


    });

    $('.my-text-box').blur(function() {
      toggleVisiblity($(this), false);
    });

    toggleVisiblity = function(element, editMode) {
      var textBlock,
        textBox;

      if (editMode === true) {
        textBlock = element;
        textBox = element.next();
        textBlock.hide();
        textBox.show().focus();
        textBox[0].value = textBox[0].value;
      } else {
        textBlock = element.prev();
        textBox = element;
        textBlock.show();
        textBox.hide();
        textBlock.html(textBox.val());
      }
    };
  };

  var $edit = $('.makeEditable').editable();
});


function myFunction(val) {
  document.writeln(val);
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<div class="makeEditable" id="fname">First Name</div>
<div class="makeEditable" id="lname">Last Name</div>
<div class="makeEditable" id="contacts">00 000 0000</div>
<div class="makeEditable" id="email">test@yourdomain.com</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: where do you want to use the id?

Comment: actually i what it for pass to another page.i'm planing to do somthing like this...

window.location.href = "test.php?id=" + ID + "&value=" +val ;

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `div` `id` when it's changed to an input field like the following.

In the `if (editMode === true) {}` block, add `var divId = element.attr('id'));` like below.

```
if (editMode === true) {
    var divId = element.attr('id'));
    console.log(divId);
}
```